# generator that does not necessarily yield anything

Tags: python

I want to have a generator that may or may not have anything to yield, and if `.next()` or similar is used it will not have a `StopIteration` error if none of the conditions to yield are met.

An example:

```
def A(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
        if x == 1:
           yield True
```

Which works like the following:

```
>>> list(A([1,2]))
[True]
>>> A([1]).next()
True
>>> A([2]).next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

But what I would want is for `A([2]).next()` to return is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

generally, in these circumstances you'd use the builtin `next` function:

```
my_iterator = A([2])
value = next(my_iterator, None)
```

In addition to being able to pass an optional "default" value when the iterator is empty, `next` has the advantage of working on python2.x and python3.x where the name of the method changes to `__next__`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def A(iterable):
    for x in iterable:
       yield True if x == 1 else None
```

Comment: Or just use separate  ```yield```  statements in each suite of an if/else *statement*.